# How to add data labels to Column chart?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, charts

I am new to SSRS 2008.  I added a column chart to my report, but I do not see a way to add data labels to this chart.  How do I do this?

Thank you, Scott.  I checked but I do not see Show Data Labels.  All it says is: Chart properties, Chart area properties, Series properties, Legend properties, Layout, Select, change chart type, and add new title, legend, or chart area.  Am I looking in the correct place?

Comment: Have you checked to see "Show Data Labels" is selected when you right-click on the chart?  http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-reporting/33089/SSRS-2008-charts-actual-value-of-bar

Comment: You have to actually right click on the bar not the area around the bar in the design view

Answer (score 8):

Right click on **any** of the bars showing on the chart that you are interested in - click 'show data labels' (Second from bottom)

Answer (score 0):

In the series properties, set "show data labels" to true.

Answer (score 0):

Point your cursor exactly to the chart (bars/column), then right click. you will see the "Show Data Labels" option.